# popups in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i want to display the pop ups in asp.net page like how the stack over flow show the pop ups on the top of the site (you get the new answer for the question like that in a orange color) how can i write the code is there any free source code or any reference. thank you

Comment: ...too many words. moved to answers section

Comment: @Robin_Day, not exactly the whole story there... you just see an empty div for the most part. There is always the javascript being processed by the page, where the real magic lies, but that's part of the source for StackOverflow and I'd not want to recommend scraping that without express permission from Jeff or Joel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not a 'popup', its probably just a standard DIV that has its height and content changed dynamically. You can do a "view source" on the page to locate the item, or use firebug (easier).

After looking, its a div called 'notify-container'.

Comment: Mr. stingyjack ya it is a div. so i can i use a div on the top for registration page of my application when user register successfully i display the div in that place the text uploaded successfully am i right

Comment: Yep. jQuery or custom javascript will help you with the 'animation' of the div.

Please, no 'Mr.'... thats my father =)

Answer (score 2):

Given below are the steps to achieve what you want.

1. Have a div (a container) to show your updates
2. Create a window.setTimeout to execute a JS function (AJAX)
3. In that function check for updates from server
4. Finally if there are any updates then show it in the div container
5. When there are updates then again setTimeout to make it invisible over a period of time (say 3 secs)

To achieve this in a very easy fashion use JS libraries like JQuery.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

These days, all that wizzery is generally done with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The asp.net ajax control toolkit has that. [Check it out here.](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/PopupControl/PopupControl.aspx)

Comment: That page demonstrates the adding of a pop window to a control, in the example, a calendar on a date entry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that's done using a holding container at the top of the page, a timer to periodically query an AJAX enabled method for updates which replaces the content of the container based on the response.